# Switch a member function name based on its version

Tags: c++, version, vtk, member-functions

I am using VTK to do something, but my question could be general.

In VTK version < 6.0, a class `vtkPolyDataMapper` has a member function called `SetInput`, but in its version 6.0, it is changed to `SetInputData`. So in version 6, I have to,

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> polyDataMapper 
    = vtkPolyDataMapper::New();

polyDataMapper->SetInputData(polyData);
// polyDataMapper->SetInput(polyData);
```

Ideally, I was hoping this situation could be handled as easy as

```
if (vtkVersion::GetVTKMajorVersion() < 6)
{
    plane->SetInput(rgrid);
}
else
{
    plane->SetInputData(rgrid);
}
```

But you know this is not correct, so my question is: what is the best way in C++ to handle this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you seem to know, you can't let the choice be made at runtime, because compilation will fail.

Instead, you can take advantage of the *preprocessor* to pass the correct code to the compiler. This is possible because VTK exposes its version in a preprocessor macro for you:

```
#if (VTK_MAJOR_VERSION < 6)
plane->SetInput(rgrid);
#else
plane->SetInputData(rgrid);
#endif
```

Comment: C'mon - _explain_ your answers!